# How to pass the inbound request body to the backend service in Azure API Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management, ibm-api-management

I am trying to generate the Active Directory Token via the Azure API gateway. For that i have created a API operation on my Azure API Gateway which accepts the following body parama.

```
  {
     "client_id" :"****************",
     "scope":"https://graph.windows.net/.default",
     "client_secret":"****************",
     "grant_type":"client_credentials"  
  }
```

Whenever I try to test this the body is set for the inboud process but not able to forward the same to the backend service which is **https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{ID}}/oauth2/v2.0/token/** so I modified my inboud policy as below but still no luck.

```
        <set-method>POST</set-method>
    <set-variable name="requestBodyData" value="@(context.Request.Body.As<string>(preserveContent: true))" />
    <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
        <value>"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"</value>
    </set-header>
    <rewrite-uri template="/" />
    <set-body>@{
          return "client_id=*******&scope=https://graph.windows.net/.default&client_secret=*******&grant_type=client_credentials";
      }</set-body>
    <!--  Don't expose APIM subscription key to the backend. -->
    <set-header name="Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" exists-action="delete" />
```

Any leads would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it , removed the headed and the method from the inbound policy and updated the inbound policy as :-

```
    <set-variable name="client_id" value="********" />
    <set-variable name="scope" value="********"" />
    <set-variable name="client_secret" value="********" />
    <set-variable name="grant_type" value="********" />
    <rewrite-uri template="/" />
    <set-body>@{
        return "client_id="+(context.Variables["client_id"])+"&scope="+(context.Variables["scope"])+"&client_secret="+(context.Variables["client_secret"])+"&grant_type="+(context.Variables["grant_type"]);
        }</set-body>
    <!--  Don't expose APIM subscription key to the backend. -->
    <set-header name="Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" exists-action="delete" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `<set-backend-service base-url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token" />` under `inbound` attribute.

Here is a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55399293/why-does-set-body-policy-not-recognize-my-post-body) you could refer to.

Comment: Thanks @joey this seems to be a workaround as my backend is already setup. Will try.

Comment: I tried this but same "Bad Request" response comes back. 
` "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'.\r\nTrace ID: *************0\r\nCorrelation ID: ****************\r\nTimestamp: ********",`